# What should I call a partial subgroup lattice diagram?

Tags: group-theory

I have this figure in a paper:

[image]

It depicts the group $\mathbb{Z}_v$ and subgroups $R=\langle r \rangle$, $C=\langle c \rangle$ and $RC=\langle r,c \rangle$.

*Question*: What should I call this diagram?  Or, please complete this sentence: "These groups are depicted by the following [something]."

It's something like a partial [subgroup lattice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_of_subgroups), or partial [Hasse diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse_diagram), but this sounds clunky.

Comment: I don't think it sounds that clunky. And, clunky or not, I'd know what you meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, we used the phrase:

> These groups are depicted by the (partial) subgroup lattice:

in the publication ([link](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s10623-014-9977-x)).  None of the referees thought it was a problem.